# saving JSON response based on timestamp to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, json

Through an API, I am getting following JSON response,

```
status: "550",
created: "2012-07-02 19:00:58",
reason: "550 #5.1.0 Address rejected. ",
email: "somemail@dummy.org"
```

I want this response to be saved in to database,

each time database is populated, I need "Created" field, which is infact a timestamp, to be unique, The script I am going to write is basically a cron job, so I dont want to add same record many times in database,

How I can I populate database, based on timestamp?

also, how can I extract bounce code extracted from

```
reason: "550 #5.1.0 Address rejected. ",
```

here the bounce code is

> 5.1.0

guide me please,

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Your question shows no research or effort

Comment: I am confused at how I can match timestamp before I add the record

Comment: I am asking for guideline, not for code, give me some guideline please, and I will try, just some way out, just some tips, to strat from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 - Avoid duplicate entries**

**Make the column unique** - Add a [`UNIQUE` index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) to the timestamp column, so that the database server complains if you are trying to insert the same one again.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_of_index ON tablename (created);
```

After this you can [`INSERT IGNORE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) or [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html) the table and it will fail or update the existing row.

**Check if the value exists** - You could just execute a query before inserting anything, checking if the timestamp exists.

```sql
SELECT count(created) FROM tablename WHERE created = '2012-07-02 19:00:58';
```

If the results is `> 0` you know that you already have a row with that timestamp so you do not insert. This is safe if noone else puts anything in that DB between your query and insert statement.

**Always delete and insert** - A third way is to prophylactically delete all rows with that timestamp and insert a row afterwards.

```sql
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE created = '2012-07-02 19:00:58';
```

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename [...];
```

But as I do not really get what you are trying to do here, you would need to edit your question and be more concrete.

**2 - extract bounce code**

Depends on what those reasons can look like. You could get to the code by [extracting the string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) between `#` and the first following `space` if it is safe to assume that there is no other `#`. No need for regular expressions here. Or simply refer to [André Catita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11352079/95033).

Comment: Voted your answer up for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

To get the bounce code, use regex.
Simple way is:

```
$string = 'asdsa#5.3.1 A';
preg_match('/#(.+) /is', $string, $match);
echo $match[1]; // match[1] will be '5.1.0'
```

And I'm assuming you want to transform the 'created' variable into the timestamp?
Just use strtotime, since the date you are receiving is a valid compound format to the function and it will work properly, like the following below.

```
$created = '2012-07-02 19:00:58';
$timestamp = strtotime($created);
```

That way you turn the date into timestamp, then just make sure the column of the timestamp is unique.

Comment: thanks...just onething more, how can I match timestamp of table before updating it with new record..i dont want to have same record multiple time, Although Wolfram gave few hints, but I am still not getting it all,,,

Comment: If you need to check, just right up do a: `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE timestamp=?^ (Where ? stands for the timestamp variable in PHP). Or just make the colum timestamp UNIQUE (unless you are receiving multiple results at the same second and time), so it won't get added multiple times.
Look up for UNIQUE in your column, if you are using PHPMYAdmin check the options of the column.